# Solving linear dispersive wave equation with Fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I want to solve the following linear dispersive wave equation.

$$u_t+u_x+u_{xxx}=0 \tag{1}$$

In particular, I want to see how a simple waveform evolves over time. Because it's linear, I know the general solution can be put into the form of a Fourier expansion (inverse Fourier transform),

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(k)e^{i(kx-\omega(k))t}dk \tag{2}$$

Where $\omega(k)$ represents the dispersion relation dictated by the wave equation. Upon plugging in the Fourier component $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ into the differential equation, I find the following dispersion relation to hold.

$$\omega(k)=k-k^3 \tag{3}$$

For my initial condition, I would like to try to model the evolution of a simple Gaussian function.

$$u(x,0)=u_0(x)=e^{-\pi x^2} \longrightarrow g(k)=\mathscr{F}[u_0(x)](k)=e^{-\pi k^2} \tag{4}$$

Plugging (3) and (4) into (1) gives the solution:

$$\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi k^2}e^{i(kx-(k-k^3))t}dk\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(it)k^3-\pi k^2+i(x-t)k}dk \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

**My question:** What I have here is a sort of "cubic exponential" inside the integral. How would I go about solving this? If I factor that cubic polynomial out into the form $k(k-\alpha_-)(k-\alpha_+)$, I make no progress. Is there an easy way to do this integral [(5)]?